# Finite group automorphism must be $x\mapsto x^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory

> **Problem**. Let $G$ be a finite group and $f\in \text{Aut}(G)$. Suppose $f$ maps more than three fourths of the elements of $G$ to their respective inverses. Prove that $f(x)=x^{-1}$ for each $x\in G$ (hence $G$ must be Abelian).

My attempt:

Define $A=\{ x\in G\mid f(x)=x^{-1}\}$. Then, by hypothesis, $|A|>\frac{3}{4}|G|$. Since $G$ is finite and $A\subset G$ all what's left to prove is that $|A|=|G|$ or $f(A)=G$... I don't know where to go from this...

Maybe I'm not going through the right path... Any help or hints are appreciated.

Comment: Please note that the answer I gave you a few minutes you posted this question was wrong: $A$ is not necessarily a subgroup; take $f=id$ and $G=S_3$, for example.

Comment: Can't believe it, I've been trying to prove $A<G$ and got nothing! Thanks so much for this comment!

Comment: Also, I just realized that this proof [is on Groups Wiki](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Automorphism_sends_more_than_three-fourths_of_elements_to_inverses_implies_abelian).